# Simple clicker with button using Visual Studio

Tags: c#

I have a problem. So i was trying to do simple cliker using button: it counts button clicks.
I was searching it on internet and tryed this code:

```
{
    int intClicks = 0;
    intClicks++;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
        Lab1.Text = ("button has been clicked " + intClicks + (intClicks == 1 ? " time." : " times."));
    }
}
```

But it only count once. I don't have idea how to reapiar this.

I want it to count EVERY button click.

Comment: What UI framework are you using? WinForms or WPF? You need to show more of your code. It looks like it "counts only once" because everytime you click the count is reset to 0 and then incremented once. Not sure why there is a loop at all...

Comment: You need to make `intClicks` a member of the component so the count can be remembered. A local variable is lost as soon as the button click handler method has finished executing.

Comment: You put "int intClicks = 0;" in the click event, and "intClicks" will become 0 every time the button is clicked. You can put "int intClicks = 0;" outside the click event to solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

As @Good Night Nerd Pride mentioned, you "forgetting" clicks count by resetting it to 0 at each button click.

To "remember" clicks count, your `int` variable should be declared somewhere out of Button.Click event handler scope.

From "Lab1.Text" i decided that you using Windows Forms (`Label` control with `Text` property), so declaring `int` variable to "remember" total clicks count out of Button.Click event handler may look like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{    
    // ... some other stuff

    private int _totalClicks;

    private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _totalClicks++;
        Lab1.Text = $"Button has been clicked {_totalClicks} {(_totalClicks == 1 ? "time" : "times")}";
    }
```

And when you need to reset it - you probably want some other `Button`, which sets `_totalClicks` variable to 0 (and clears `Label.Text` if needed):

```
private void ButtonReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _totalClicks = 0;
    Lab1.Text = string.Empty;
}
```